# Getting 'android.app.RemoteServiceException' crash on Play store console

Tags: android, service

I have been getting the following crash report on Play store console:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2240)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8512)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

This crash is happening on Android 11 mostly and Google Pixel and Samsung devices. I have searched on the internet but found no help regarding this issue.